# Change eclipse selected row highlight color in Ctrl + 1 or Ctrl + Shift + T like menues

Tags: eclipse, themes, color-scheme

[image: Highlighted bright white on a dark theme]

As you can see, when using a dark theme (and thus bright letters), this selection highlight makes the underlying text absolutely unreadable.

I have been unable to find what setting dictates this color.

This problem occurs in every popup selection menu. Sadly I have no idea how these things are officially called, so I have been unable to google a solution.

Comment: It looks you are using an outdated Eclipse version and not the default Dark theme. Upgrading to Eclipse Oxygen.3a (4.7.3a) and using the default Dark theme should fix this bug.

Comment: @howlger  Yep, eclipse 4.7.2 this might be the cause.